# In AndEngine ESGL1 how to animate background?

Tags: android, andengine

I need to animate my background which have 6 images and that needed to repeat again and again(123456123456...). So can any one help in this. 
Thanks

Comment: How do you mean animate? such as flipping through 6 different images every couple of seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the class AnimatedSprite?